# Arrayoutofboundsexception using setspan

Tags: android, android-layout

I receive an arrayoutofboundsexception error. When I attempt to format a draft text message to be displayed. This is just a simple text-messaging app and I am attempting to set the text size and color. When I comment these two lines my app does not crash but is not formatted as I would like.

The error occurs at:

```
buf.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), size, color), before,
buf.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Here is the entire code:

```
private CharSequence formatMessage(ConversationListItemData ch) {
    final int size = android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small;
    final int color = android.R.attr.textColorSecondary;
    String from = ch.getFrom();

    SpannableStringBuilder buf = new SpannableStringBuilder(from);

    if (ch.getMessageCount() > 1) {
        buf.append(" (" + ch.getMessageCount() + ") ");
    }

    int before = buf.length();
    if (ch.hasDraft()) {
        buf.append(" ");
        buf.append(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.has_draft));
        buf.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), size, color), before,
                buf.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        buf.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                getContext().getResources().getColor(R.drawable.text_color_red)),
                before, buf.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    // Unread messages are shown in bold
    if (!ch.isRead()) {
        buf.setSpan(STYLE_BOLD, 0, buf.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You cannot use the TextAppearanceSpan constructor that has 3 parameters when using ForegroundColorSpan. I changed the line below by removing the color variable parameter:

```
buf.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), size, color), before,
        buf.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

to

```
buf.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), size), before,
        buf.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```